# Cannot scroll webpage if cursor is over Azure Media Player element

Tags: html, css, scroll, html5-video, azure-media-player

When including Azure Media Player in a html webpage, I cannot scroll the webpage vertically with mouse wheel if the cursor is over the player element.

The goal is to achieve the opposite behavior, scroll the page even if the cursor is over the player.

I could reproduce the issue on Chrome and Edge while on Firefox the issue is not present.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/buliko/h3106w9z/

I tried to apply `pointer-events: none;` to the video html element which solved the scrolling issue but unfortunately hovering on the player did not make the control bar display. I tried to programmatically display the control bar on `mouseenter` event by calling `player.controls(true)` which did not help.

Is there any way to fix this issue? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try -

```
.amp-default-skin .vjs-text-track-display {
    pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

Comment: Almost there! When I click on the video it does not trigger play/pause operations.

Comment: @Buliko but i am able to do that in the fiddle you provided.

Comment: In Chrome the controls are working but when I click on the video itself nothing happens. Modified version https://jsfiddle.net/buliko/h3106w9z/14/